# Using SAXON Xpath engine in Java

Tags: java, xpath, saxon

Here is my code :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // System.setProperty(
    // "javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory", 
    // "net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl");

    String xml="<root><a>#BBB#</a><a>#CCC#</a><b><a>#DDD#</a></b></root>";
    try{
        JDocument dom = new JDocument(xml);

        XPathFactory factory = net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl.newInstance();
        XPath xpath = factory.newXPath();
        XPathExpression expr = xpath.compile("//a[matches(.,'#...#')]");

        Object result = expr.evaluate(dom, XPathConstants.NODESET);
        NodeList nodes = (NodeList) result;
        Nodes sharped = new Nodes(nodes);

        for (Node n:sharped){
            System.out.println(n.toString());
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

And I get this :

```
javax.xml.transform.TransformerException: Impossible to find the function : matches
at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.error(XPathParser.java:608)
at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.FunctionCall(XPathParser.java:1505)
at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.PrimaryExpr(XPathParser.java:1444)
at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.FilterExpr(XPathParser.java:1343)
at org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser.PathExpr(XPathParser.java:1276)
```

Which means Java is using `org.apache.xpath.compiler.XPathParser` class when I clearly created my factory through `net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl`.

(I actually only need to put some `matches` in my xpaths... so if any solution not involving Saxon is known, consider my need reached).

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From Saxon examples :

```
System.setProperty("javax.xml.xpath.XPathFactory:"+NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON, "net.sf.saxon.xpath.XPathFactoryImpl");
XPathFactory xpf = XPathFactory.newInstance(NamespaceConstant.OBJECT_MODEL_SAXON);
```

Works fine.

Comment: If you are confused about the jar files, you need to add saxon core and saxon dome to your dependencies in order to make it work, or you will get a ""Cannot locate an object model implementation for nodes of class com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.dom.DeferredDocumentImpl" Exception

Comment: How do I do the opposite, that is, force it to use the default XPathFactory in the JVM (instead of Saxon)?

Comment: No James, because we want to use XPath 2.0 functions like 'matches' here.

Comment: Anyway, this workaround does not work in my case, without error or warning, but empty value after evaluation of any function..
NB : I use the docFactory.setNamespaceAware(false);