# Issue with Saxon and Xalan in my WebApp when defining a SOAP connector using Spring

Tags: spring, soap, saxon, xalan

I am trying to add a SOAP Web Service to an existing application and am having a large amount of trouble due to Saxon / Xalan conflicts. When my Web Application starts I always get the error:

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown type of result: class javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult
```

Stack Trace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown type of result: class javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMResult
at net.sf.saxon.event.SerializerFactory.getReceiver(SerializerFactory.java:154)
at net.sf.saxon.IdentityTransformer.transform(IdentityTransformer.java:24)
at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerHelper.transform(TransformerHelper.java:138)
at org.springframework.xml.transform.TransformerObjectSupport.transform(TransformerObjectSupport.java:96)
at org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.InliningXsdSchemaTypesProvider.getSchemaElement(InliningXsdSchemaTypesProvider.java:113)
at org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.provider.InliningXsdSchemaTypesProvider.addTypes(InliningXsdSchemaTypesProvider.java:101)
at org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.ProviderBasedWsdl4jDefinition.afterPropertiesSet(ProviderBasedWsdl4jDefinition.java:233)
at org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition.afterPropertiesSet(DefaultWsdl11Definition.java:182)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1419)
```

I prototyped the creation of a SOAP Web Service in a stand-alone Web Application and it worked fine. Checking the prototype, there was no reference to Saxon and transformers were of type:

```
com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl
```

Adding the code to my existing (large) Web Application was simple but when transforms occurred the Transform object was of type:

```
  net.sf.saxon.IdentityTransformer
```

Now Saxon is used by parts of the application and (probably) cannot just be removed. (I have gone done this route and it appears to be a can of worms). I am using a DefaultWsdl11Definition object to create my WSDL schema. How can I state that the transforms for this aspect of the application should use Xalan rather than Saxon? I am using Spring to wire everything up and my servlet class for the SOAP Web Service is:

```
<bean id="projectSearch" class="org.springframework.ws.wsdl.wsdl11.DefaultWsdl11Definition">
  <property name="schema" ref="schema"/>
  <property name="portTypeName" value="ProjectSearch"/>
  <property name="targetNamespace" value="http://FOO.FOO/foo"/>
  <property name="locationUri" value="/soap/reso"/>
  <property name="requestSuffix" value="Request"/>
  <property name="responseSuffix" value="Response"/>                                   
</bean>
<bean id="schema" class="org.springframework.xml.xsd.SimpleXsdSchema">
  <property name="xsd" value="/WEB-INF/ws-project.xsd"/>
</bean>
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to resolve my Saxon / Xalan woes?

Thanks,

Phil

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Xalan alongside Saxon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11224850/using-xalan-alongside-saxon)