# java xpath XML parsing

Tags: java, xml, xpath, xml-parsing, string-parsing

I've written some code to extract different parts of from an XML string using xpath. The question I have is if the xml string was for example

```
<event>alarm, red, 2</event>
```

is there any easy way with xpath to select say the second word in the string  after the first comma so "red"?? right now i am using

```
String event = xpath.evaluate("/event", doc);
```

which returns `"alarm, red, 2"` but all i want is `"red"`. I know that i could just then take event and use substring to extract `"red"` but i am wondering if there is a way to do this using xpath rather than substring?

code:

```
String xml = "<event>alarm, red, 2<event>";  

XPathFactory xpathFactory = XPathFactory.newInstance();
XPath xpath = xpathFactory.newXPath();

InputSource source = new InputSource(new StringReader(xml));
Document doc = (Document) xpath.evaluate ("/", source, XPathConstants.NODE);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use an XPath 2.0 implementation, you can use `tokenize` and use a regular expression to split the string by the comma and then select the second token:

```
tokenize(/event, ',')[2]
```

Comment: awesome! how would I implement this into my code? something like String event = xpath.evaluate("/event", doc).tokenize(/event, '2')[2];??

Comment: `tokenize` is XPath 2.0, so you need an implementation which supports it such as Saxon 9. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/926222/using-saxon-xpath-engine-in-java) about setting up Saxon in Java.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's possible & it's probably not a good idea to do that, content of your element is supposed to be atomic, I would avoid mixing this parsing with Xpath and simply wrap the event with a utility method garbing the first word.