# Use XSLT to exactly match XML text containing &quot; or &apos;

Tags: java, xml, xslt, saxon

I am working on a Java Application which, includes the Saxon Package to use XSLT to match text strings in XML and return the ISBN Number.

Below is a sample of the Library XML:

```
<Library>
        <Book>
            <Title>Easy Book</Title>
            <ISBN>978-3-16-148410-0</ISBN>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Title>Tiger&apos;s Naptime Book</Title>
            <ISBN>978-3-16-148410-1</ISBN>
        </Book>
        <Book>
            <Title>How to &quot;Capture&quot; a Clever Tiger&apos;s Toe</Title>
            <ISBN>978-3-16-148410-2</ISBN>
        </Book>
</Library>
```

The first "Easy Book" is easy to find, with XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="urn:developJava.com/NotWorking">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="Book/Title[text()='Easy Book']">
<xsl:value-of select='../ISBN' separator= ","/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But, I am unable to find the Title for example:

```
<Title>Tiger&apos;s Naptime Book</Title>
```

Using this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="urn:developJava.com/NotWorking">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="Book/Title[text()='Tiger&apos;s Naptime Book']">
<xsl:value-of select='../ISBN' separator= ","/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Or find:

```
<Title>How to &quot;Capture&quot; a Clever Tiger&apos;s Toe</Title>
```

Using this XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns1="urn:developJava.com/NotWorking">
<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="Book/Title[text()='How to &quot;Capture&quot; a Clever Tiger&apos;s Toe']">
<xsl:value-of select='../ISBN' separator= ","/>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

It is handling the embedded text delimiter characters of `&quot;` and `&apos;` in the title that is the problem. Your thoughts on how to handle this XML/XSLT would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may find this useful:

[Using an xpath to find text with an apostrophe ( " ' ")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42834302/using-an-xpath-to-find-text-with-an-apostrophe/42845328#42845328)

The general rule is:

- to escape the quotes used as your XPath string delimiter, double them: `'Tiger''s Naptime Book'`
- to escape the quotes used as the XML attribute delimiter, write them as `&quot;` or `&apos;`: `match="Book/Title[text()='How to &quot;Capture&quot; a Clever Tiger''s Toe']"`

To understand how it works, remember that XML parsing happens before XPath parsing, so the expansion of XML entities like `&quot;` needs to deliver an attribute value that's a valid XPath expression.

Also, there's another solution which may be more readable:

```
<xsl:variable name="q">How to "Capture" a Clever Tiger's Toe</xsl:variable>
<xsl:template match="*[contains(., $q)]"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Michael!

This is the correct answer to my question, from literally the gentleman who wrote the book! I'll just add a brief code example:

```
  public static void main(String[] args) {
      
      String inXML = "<Library>\r\n" + 
            "       <Book>\r\n" +
            "           <Title>Easy Book</Title>\r\n" + 
            "           <ISBN>978-3-16-148410-1</ISBN>\r\n" + 
            "      </Book>\r\n" + 
            "       <Book>\r\n" + 
            "           <Title>Tiger&apos;s Naptime Book</Title>\r\n" + 
            "           <ISBN>978-3-16-148410-1</ISBN>\r\n" + 
            "      </Book>\r\n" + 
            "       <Book>\r\n" + 
            "           <Title>How to &quot;Capture&quot; a Clever Tiger&apos;s Toe</Title>\r\n" + 
            "           <ISBN>978-3-16-148410-2</ISBN>\r\n" + 
            "      </Book>\r\n" +
            "   </Library>";
      
       // BUILD THE CUSTOM XSLT FOR THE modelPath
            String stylesheet1 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" + 
                    "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"2.0\"\r\n" +
                    "xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\"\r\n" +
                    " xmlns:ns1=\"urn:developJava.com/Working\">\r\n" +
                    "<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration=\"yes\"/>\n" + "<xsl:template match=\"Book/Title[text()='Tiger&apos;&apos;s Naptime Book']\">\n" +
                    "<xsl:value-of select='../ISBN' separator= \",\"/>\r\n" +
                    "</xsl:template>\r\n" +
                    "<xsl:template match=\"text()\"/>\r\n" + 
                    "</xsl:stylesheet>\r\n";
            
            // BUILD THE CUSTOM XSLT FOR THE modelPath
            String stylesheet2 = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?>\r\n" + 
                    "<xsl:stylesheet version=\"2.0\"\r\n" +
                    "xmlns:xsl=\"http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform\"\r\n" +
                    " xmlns:ns1=\"urn:developJava.com/Working\">\r\n" +
                    "<xsl:output omit-xml-declaration=\"yes\"/>\n" + "<xsl:template match=\"Book/Title[text()='How to &quot;Capture&quot; a Clever Tiger&apos;&apos;s Toe']\">\r\n" +
                    "<xsl:value-of select='../ISBN' separator= \",\"/>\r\n" +
                    "</xsl:template>\r\n" +
                    "<xsl:template match=\"text()\"/>\r\n" + 
                    "</xsl:stylesheet>\r\n";
            
    
            String result1 = "";
            try {
                result1 = XsltMethods.transformUsingXslt(stylesheet1, inXML);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            
            System.out.println("result 1:---" + result1 + "---");
            
            String result2 = "";
            try {
                result2 = XsltMethods.transformUsingXslt(stylesheet2, inXML);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            
            System.out.println("result 2:---" + result2 + "---");
      }
      
      private static String transformUsingXslt(String stylesheet, String inXml)
                throws IOException {

            // CONVERT Strings TO AN INPUT FORM ACCEPTABLE TO XSLT TRANSFORMER
            Source xsltSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(stylesheet));
            Source xmlSource = new StreamSource(new StringReader(inXml));

            StringWriter writer = null;
            String result = null;

            try {

                writer = new StringWriter();

                TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance("net.sf.saxon.TransformerFactoryImpl", null);
                // TransformerFactory tFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = tFactory.newTransformer(xsltSource);
                transformer.transform(xmlSource, new javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult(writer));

                result = writer.toString();

            } catch (TransformerConfigurationException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (TransformerException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return result;
        }
```

Executing the code returns the following results:

result 1:---978-3-16-148410-1---

result 2:---978-3-16-148410-2---

Comment: You don't need the entity reference for the single quote i.e. instead of `&apos;&apos;` you can simply use `''`.

Comment: The fact that you've got XPath embedded in XSLT embedded in Java, with each level having its own escaping conventions, certainly complicates things. It's a shame Java doesn't have verbatim string literals like C#.

Comment: I couldn't agree more! This is actually an application that I've inherited and I'm trying to make it run with minimal enhancements. The "real" XML for the application is actually quite ugly and can contain just about anything. I'd like to rewrite the search classes to parse the source XML data and exclude the XSLT altogether. Thank you again for your knowledge and insights!